# How do I make a WPF button (e.g. OK) the standard size?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I want to add an OK button that has a default size. When I say default, I mean a using the [recommended sizing and spacing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-command-buttons#recommended-sizing-and-spacing). As it's in a Grid I get it stretched, but is there a size that people use or obtain it from the OS?

```xml
<Button Content="OK" />
```

If I was to add a Cancel button, how would you lay this out? Spacing etc.

Comment: put it in a standard sized container?

Comment: I updated the question to make it specific to the Windows guidelines. It can be reopened now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with setting an exact size is it would not cope well with different languages, if you ever implement that.

However, "OK" is always so tiny, and corresponding buttons being different sizes looks silly. So I'd recommend using a "shared size group". This will adapt to changes in language/content, and should always be nicely proportioned:

```
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Children>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="OK"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Cancel"/>
    </Grid.Children>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no "standard size" for an OK button and I don't think Microsoft have specified one in design guidelines. That is for you to decide. By default the WPF button will size to its content ("OK"). If you have multiple command buttons next to each other it is good to make them equal size. Choose a size that fits the content of each one comfortably and aligns well with other controls.

Comment: There is a standard size. It's [50 DLU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-command-buttons#recommended-sizing-and-spacing).